# Could not read from remote repository https

Tags: git, github

I  am a new git user.

I am using the git version 2.8.2.

I have access (to push /pull ) to a private repository.

I cloned the repo using https ( not SSH )

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/UserLab/project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/UserLab/project.git (push)
```

I want to be able to push/pull to/from develop branch.

```
 git branch -r  -v
 origin/HEAD      -> origin/master
 origin/OneUser   
 origin/master   
 origin/develop
```

So,the origin/develop branch exists,right?

I am trying (either push either fetch):

```
git push -u origin/develop OneUser
```

and it gives me:

```
fatal: 'origin/develop' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(I read posts about this error but most of them had to do with SSH access)

Comment: It looks like you don't have push permissions to that particular repository. Make sure you have them.

Comment: @Venky:I have permission level `Admin` as I can see from github settings.

Comment: A good place to start would be https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push -u origin develop`

Space not slash '/' between repo and branch. That is why it says "'origin/develop' does not appear to be a git repository" because it's trying to find a remote called origin/develop, which doesn't exist (the remote is called origin).

Comment: :But I want to push from `OneUser` branch to 'develop` branch ( so , `origin/develo` ).With your command I will push from `develop` branch to `origin` , right?

Comment: `git checkout OneUser && git push origin develop`, although I think you want to merge changes from OneUser to develop instead. Pushing from one branch into another is bad practice imho

Comment: :You mean first `checkout OneUser` in order to be in that branch?And then `push origin develop` ?And it will push from `OneUser` to `develop`?Because the push command just says from develop to origin.I don't want to make any mistake and push to `origin` (master)branch.Thanks

Comment: For the beginners the following link will be helpful in understanding git commands and flow  [http://learngitbranching.js.org/?NODEMO]

Comment: Yes most git commands operate from your current branch. As @AD7six said the '-b' flag will create your local branch if you haven't done that already

Comment: @AD7six:In the link you gave me , it shows `push origin OneUser` and not `push origin develop` as above.

Comment: @LiquidityC:You mean I need first to fetch and merge before doing push?

Comment: @LiquidityC:You suggest to do first : `git checkout OneUser` ,`git fetch origin develop` , `git merge origin develop` ? And then do the push?

Comment: @George I'm actually not sure. It's hard to understand what you are trying to attempt by pushing work from one branch to another. Usually this is what I do when working with git: `git checkout <branch>` do some work, check the work with `git status` and `git diff` commit the work onto the branch `git commit -a`, check my new commit with `git log -3` and then push the branch with my new commit to the repo `git push origin <branch>`. If you come from a CVS/SVN background then this is a bit different from what you are accustomed too.

Comment: @LiquidityC:I think it is almost the same.The difference is that I am working in my branch and push to develop (another branch ).I created another issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182049/push-failed-merge-returned-already-up-to-date/37182602#37182602)