# push failed ( merge returned `already up to date ` )

Tags: git, github

I want to fetch and merge the changes that have been done in `develop` branch into my branch `OneUser`.

I am doing:

```
git checkout OneUser
git fetch origin develop  

...
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
From https://github.com/.........
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   e2f......... d36  develop    -> origin/develop

git merge origin develop

Already up-to-date.
```

git commit -a

(I know that some changes have been done, so normally it should give me some conflicts?Or what it has been changed? )

Then , if I try to push my changes to develop :

```
git checkout OneUser
git push -u origin develop

 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.../.git
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

========= Α workflow ========================

```
git checkout -b OneUser develop
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop

//fetch from develop branch and merge to OneUser
git checkout OneUser
git fetch origin develop
git merge origin/develop

If you have any conflicts ,solve , add files and commit.

//work on branch
git add “files”
git commit -m “message”

//push to develop
git push origin OneUser:develop
```

Comment: The workflow is fine and should work, puritans may argue about pushing to another branch, an alternate puritan ending to your workflow can be:   
    `// merge your local branch to local develop`
    `git checkout develop`
    `git merge OneUser`
    `git push origin develop`

Comment: @dubes:Ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to push your local branch `OneUser` to the remote branch `develop`

In that case, you will have to tell git so

```
git push origin OneUser:develop
```

This tells git to push to origin repository your branch (OneUser) to the develop branch in remote.

**Why you faced the error:**

```
git checkout OneUser
git push -u origin develop

 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
```

with `git push -u origin develop`, you were instructing git to: 
push your ***local*** branch named "develop" to the remote branch which matches the name. Since you had merged to your `OneUser` branch, but not updated your local copy of the develop branch, git failed to push. You can also see it in the error message:

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
```

**Update #1**
Seems like in your scenario, you would always like to sync your `OneUser` branch with `develop`, in that case, you can explicitly ask git to treat it so, by issuing the command (1 time only)

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop
```

You can check which remote branch is being tracked by:

```
git status -sb
```

Then it is simply the matter of pushing your "local" branch, git will know where to push it.

```
git push origin OneUser
```

Comment: :And what is the difference with the `git checkout OneUser
git push -u origin develop`

Comment: :Generally, I am working on my branch `OneUser` and then want to push/pull my changes to/from `develop` branch

Comment: @George updated my answer with explanation why you were facing the error. If you want your local branch to be in sync with the develop branch, you can use --set-upstream-to or do -u but with complete reference. I will update my answer with more details and hints

Comment: Glad that worked! I added a few more tips, in case they help :-)

Comment: :Ok, nice ! And if I want to untrack at some point later the develop branch? (Also,in anothe post someone told that it is not a good practise to push a branch to another.But ,there is no other way  right?

Comment: :Also,(last question :) ).if after the fetch/merge I have conflicts,I edit the files,add them and commit,right?(if I have no conflicts ,I am ok ).Thanks!

Comment: for the last question, you are correct. For the question about pushing 1 branch to another, I personally follow the following workflow, just because it works for the team and is convenient: 1. create a local branch (OneUser) from remote branch (develop) 2. work on the OneUser branch, keep merging remote develop regularly into the local branch. 3. once done, go to the local develop branch, fetch pull from remote develop to local, merge your OneUser to local develop and push local develop to remote. Graphical view: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: :I didn't understand well the second step.I updated my post.I wrote a workflow .Can you let me know if you agree ?Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you're looking for "git pull --rebase". that should integrate the remote changes, allowing you to push

Comment: well, all it does is fetch the latest commits and place all the new commits on your end on top of them so they can simply be pushed as the new commits. it sounds like exactly what you're looking for. I mean, i'm sure a merge would also work, but rebasing usually makes more sense in this case

Comment: :I resolved the conflicts ( edited the files ,add,commit) and when tried to push it gave me again the same error! I tried also `git pull --rebase` but it gives me `error: Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.`

Comment: :I did the rebase but it messed all the files I had changed!I reset it back and now my files are ok,but still i can't push.

Comment: From the error, it would appear that you have further changes that haven't been staged and comitted yet. Is that intentional, or should they be pushed as well? If they should be included, you need to stage and commit then, before running the "pull --rebase", if they should be ignored for now, you should stash them, and then do the "pull --rebase"

Comment: :I really don't remember now.But thanks for the info.